# Using presentViewController (or other techniques) to show a view but not in full screen mode?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `presentViewController` can only work in full screen mode for iPhone and iPod. However, I need a similar functionality, which can show some portion of the view from the view controller that is to be loaded (call it B).

Given a current view controller A, I want to bring up B to take some info from the user, but it has to be in a different view controller for my design purposes.

I tried to set `modalPresentationStyle` to different values and resize the view in B, but it always shows the whole view in B.

Is there anyway to show some portion of the view in B? I'm looking for something similar to the twitter's [popup](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010943), which is a view controller and can be shown with `presentViewController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iPhone and iPod you can't do this with presentViewController, as the docs say this is only for full screen ViewControllers. Your best choice is to use a child ViewController. Take a look at the ViewController containment guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: @Snppis looks like this is what I want.. will give a try and see how it goes